# Sharepoint 2013 copy values from request list to task list or vice-versa using workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I´m creating a Sharepoint 2013 workflow where there is a Resquest List and a Task List.
In the request list, a user can create a request and the approver answer on the Task List.

In the workflow, I´ve created a custom Task List, which the approver selects a option in a dropdown menu (approved or rejected) and can write a text in the comment field.

After the approver´s anwser the task, it is possible to se the approval result on the Task List. However the requester is not allowed to see this List, but only his Resquest List.

The question is: how do I link these Lists (Resquest and Task)?
How to copy column values from the Task List to Resquest List or vice-versa? So the requesters the see the approver´s anwser.
I´d tried linking by Request ID and Task ID (primary key?), but it didn´t work.
Is there a way I can bound this tables using workflow?

Thanks :)

Comment: Does the request list contain the approver's identity in a people picker field? If that data is in a column in the request list, then you can have a workflow lookup comments or other data from the task list using that value as the unique identifier (i.e. primary key) by matching to the 'Assigned To' field in the task list.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt contain. Also, the approver is always the same. 

Isnt possible to sharepoint 2013 task list find the request item´s ID? Or what about using the workflow identity? I guess that each item created creates a workflow process..

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get reference the ID of the list item on which the workflow was initiated through the 'Workflow Item ID' reference in a Task list. Then use that in a lookup to match it to the actual Current Item ID. See the screenshot below. This is using a SharePoint 2010 workflow, FYI. Options in 2013 workflows might be similar (if that's what you're using).

[image: Task List ID Lookup]

Cheers,

-Drew